# How will someone be able to log in if they removed their Facebook account and ...?

Tags: discussion, login, openid, facebook

How will someone be able to log in if they removed their Facebook account and he originally created an Stack Exchange account using it?

This is just a scenario that I conceived and was curious to know the answer.

Comment: Hopefully, before removing the facebook account, that person added another OpenId provider (or several), such as Google, Yahoo, LiveJournal, Blogger or any other provider, so they can log in with them instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you no longer can log in to your Facebook account, or any other OpenID provider you are using for a Stack Exchange account, then you can no longer log in to your Stack Exchange account either.

You can avoid this situation by adding more than one OpenId provider to your account:

[image: my logins]

[image: add more logins...]

Answer (score 8):

There's a loophole here: if you still have access to the email address associated with your Facebook account, you can register for [a Stack Exchange OpenId](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) using the same email and log into your existing Stack Exchange account using that.

We trust Facebook not to tell us you use an email address that isn't your own, so all you have to do is demonstrate ownership of that email for us to believe it's you.

If you also burn your email account, you're screwed. Unless you took [Martijn's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237989/how-will-someone-be-able-to-log-in-if-he-removed-his-facebook-account-and/237990#237990) and added a different credential before logging out.

Friendly reminder for anyone else reading this: if you're having trouble accessing your account, first try plugging a few of your email addresses into /users/account-recovery on the site where you used your account - if you were smart enough to put a valid email address on your account *somewhere* and still have access to it, you'll probably be able to regain access.