# How to log in to Stack Overflow if I lose my Facebook account?

Tags: support, login, facebook

I'm logged in to Stack Overflow from my Facebook account. Unfortunately Facebook asked me some security questions, and it seems I'm going to lose my account.

My problem is, *if* I lose it (at that time I can't login to Facebook) then how can I log in to Stack Overflow? If I log out from Stack Overflow I'm going to lose Stack Overflow access too.

Is there anything that I can do to keep access to my Stack Overflow account?

Comment: How you post now if you lost your account?

Comment: Maybe he is still logged in, but can't actually login any more (on other devices for example). The OAuth token will expire any time soon...

Comment: yes .i'm loged in.but i can't logout and re sign in

Comment: This [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237989/245360) seems related. Not sure if it applies entirely ([Shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237991/245360) might only work if the account is removed), but you could try that too.

Comment: Simply add a new OpenID.

Comment: i added a google account .but i didn't logout and try to log.i think i'm done .thanks you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more login options from your profile.

[image: Add more logins]

You can add a Stack Exchange one for a traditional email/password login, if you have no Google Account or other types of accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already locked out, you should contact the SE team. They are the only ones capable of changing your account.

You can click the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) in the page footer.

Comment: I've made a small edit. If the user still has access to their account, they don't need to contact the staff. They can add logins themselves :)

Comment: @SecondRikudo: That doesn't always seems to be necessary. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237991/245360).

Comment: Actually, it's pretty much exactly what I've said in my answer (which means this question needs to be closed as a duplicate)

Comment: @SecondRikudo: I CV'ed too. Not exactly sure if there is a difference in 'deleted' vs 'locked'.

Comment: In this context, I think it doesn't matter as long as "I don't have access to it anymore" is in effect.